# Ruby on Rails installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, osx-snow-leopard

I borrowed Agile Web Development with Rails from my local library, and for Mac development it asked me to view this article:
http://hivelogic.com/articles/ruby-rails-mongrel-mysql-osx

I'm a little bit worried about following the article because I am running Snow Leopard.  Does anyone have an article for installing Rails for Snow Leopard?  Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snow Leopard includes Rails, so it isn't necessary to install it.

But to install Rails from scratch, here is what you do:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

You then have Rails.

That tutorial includes steps such as installing Ruby from scratch, which wouldn't hurt, but isn't as necessary as it was back then (the version of 1.8.2 that Apple included was old and buggy).

Answer (score 0):

Rails is already installed on Snow Leopard, but I did use [this article](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard/) to install a separate copy in `/usr/local` (the article has links to why that is a good idea).

Comment: Unless you're using a different version of *ruby*, there's no point in installing rubygems or rails a second time over.